# C++ double buffer and memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, gdi+

Ok so my double buffer works fine but it seems that it use a lot of memory.

i know that double buffer should store a copy of the ellipse I'm drawing than paint it on the screen but it after that it deletes the copy and makes new copy but it doesn't seem to delete it 
here is my code

```
hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
HDC memDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hMemMap=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 300, 300);
HBITMAP hOldMap=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hMemMap);

// Drawing
Graphics draw(memDC);
draw.FillRectangle(&green, 0, 0, 300, 25);
Font font(&fontfamily, 14, 0, UnitPixel);
PointF p1(180.0f, 4.0f);
PointF p2(30.0f, 4.0f);
draw.DrawString(level, -1, &font, p2, &blue);
draw.DrawString(str, -1, &font, p1, &blue);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball1.Ex, ball1.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball2.Ex, ball2.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball3.Ex, ball3.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball4.Ex, ball4.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball5.Ex, ball5.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball6.Ex, ball6.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball7.Ex, ball7.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball8.Ex, ball8.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball9.Ex, ball9.Ey, 25, 25);
draw.FillEllipse(&red, ball10.Ex, ball10.Ey, 25, 25);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 300, 300, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(memDC, hOldMap);
DeleteObject(hMemMap);
DeleteDC(memDC);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it doesn't get deleted, do you mean that memory usage doesn't decrease?  Does memory usage keep increasing every time this function gets called?

Comment: I don't know about in this case, but generally double buffering doesn't involve deleting anything.  You draw to the "back buffer" (the copy the screen isn't displaying), then when you are done, you "swap buffers", so it looks like you drew everything at the same time.  You keep the old buffer around to draw on for the next frame.  Each frame, you swap which one is displayed, and which one you draw to.  There is no room for deallocation in a design like that...

Comment: yes, it increase. but it doesn't decrease

Comment: ... and each time you swap, you end up with a dirty buffer, so you have to clear out of the contents before you start drawing again.

Comment: My real question is: Does the memory usage increase each time this function gets called, or does it just increase once.  If it only increases once, then that's fine.  Just because you release the bitmap memory doesn't mean that the app will release it back to the system; it can hold on to it for future allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying all objects, but not the DC. You must call ReleaseDC after the drawing.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921543.aspx):

> *After painting with a common device context, the ReleaseDC function must be called to release the device context.*